# Given an array of single digit, positive integers, convert to a whole number, multiply by 2, return an array of new product with each digit in array

Tags: c, arrays

For example:

```
[1,2,3] -> [2,4,6]
[9,1] -> [1,8,2]
[6,7,5] -> [1,3,5,0]
```

I got this question on my first tech interview yesterday (did it in C because that's my best language, so a C answer would be help more) and completely blanked :(
This is what I was thinking:

Start at the end of the array and keeping moving left
At every `arr[i]`, multiply by 2 and see if there're 2 digits (if `arr[i]/10 != 0`) and if there is a left most digit, carry it over to `arr[i-1]` as long as `a[i-1] != NULL`.

I just could not figure out how to actually do this in C. I had something like:

```
int* multTwo(int* arr, int len) {
    int *newarr;   // I know i have to malloc, but not sure what size because
                   // wouldnt the size depend on the new number's size?
    int temp, i;
    for (i=len-1; i>=0; i--) {
       temp = arr[i]*2;
       newarr[i] = temp%2;
       if(temp/10 != 0) 
          newarr[i-1] = temp/2;
    }
    return newarr;
}
```

But there are a lot of bugs in my code. Is there a better way or am I on the right track?

Comment: Start with allocating enough buffer and assign it to `newarr`.

Comment: "wouldnt the size depend on the new number's size?" It would. Now what size the new number can possibly have? You know the size of the old number.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can think in a short time, like an interview

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void invert (int *head, int *tail)
{
    int temp;

    if (head < tail)
    {
        temp = *head;
        *head = *tail;
        *tail = temp;

        invert(++head, --tail);
    }
}

int* multTwo(int* arr, size_t len)
{
    int value = 0;
    int n_digits =0 ;

    // CONVERT THE ARRAY TO NUMBER
    while(len--)
    {
        value += *arr;

        value *=10;

        arr++;
    }

    value /= 10;

    // DOUBLE THE NUMBER
    value *= 2;

    // CONVERT IT TO BUFFER
    int *digits = malloc(sizeof(*digits));

    while ((value>0) && (digits != NULL))
    {
        digits[n_digits++] = value%10;

        value /= 10;

        digits = realloc(  digits, sizeof(*digits) * (n_digits+1) );
    }

    if (digits != NULL)
    {
        invert(digits, &digits[n_digits-1]);

        printf("[ ");

        for (int i=0; i<n_digits; i++)
            printf("%d, ", digits[i]);

        printf("]\n");
    }

    return digits;
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {6,7,5};

    multTwo(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I always liked linked-lists  - its so [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language))-ish.  Hmmm related to `LPs`?

Comment: @chux no i not related to my nick, but wake up bad days at university ;)...Lost In The Sea of Parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudo code.  The main idea is to show the depth of C knowledge as part of the interview, not Code golf.

What signature?

```
 // arr is not changed, use `const`
 // array indexing best done with `size_t`              
 int* multTwo(const int* arr, size_t len) {
```

Size needed and show error handling.  Maybe also detect `arr == NULL` when `len > 0`

```
 need = len;
 // if lead element is 5 or more, add 1.
 // Error if element is not in 0-9 range
```

Allocate memory.  Allocating to size of variable de-referenced type is less error prone, easier to review and maintain than coding the variable type.  Showing maintenance concerns during a C interview is a *good* thing.  Think if later code changed to `unsigned char* multTwo(const unsigned char* arr, size_t len) {`, no need to change `newarr = malloc(sizeof *newarr * need)`.

```
 newarr = malloc(sizeof *newarr * need)
```

Check allocation.  An allocation of 0 is OK to return NULL.  Yet maybe this routine should still allocate 1 byte, a tad wasteful, to insure a `NULL` return is an *error*.  Discussing issues like with the interviewer is good.  Shows you want to clearly understand the customer's need not just in the meat of the function, but the corner cases.

```
 if (newarr == NULL && need > 0) fail()
```

Loop though and populate the new array much like OP coded with meaningful variable names and using unsigned array indexing.

```
 size_t arr_i=len;
 size_t newarr_i=need;
 int carry = 0;
 while (arr_i > 0) 
   sum = arr[--arr_i]*2 + carry;
   newarr[--newarr_i] = sum%10;
   carry = sum/10;
 }
 if (carry) {
   newarr[--newarr_i] = carry;
 }
```

Return `newarr`

Comment: _now add 1 for each element 5 or more_.... doubling `5555` will be `5` digits, not `8`... ;)

Comment: @LPs  Ah you are correct.  I concluded incorrectly that the doubling was done on each element - oh well, looks like I don`t get the job.

Comment: ahaha. I though the same at first time, but last example didn't match ;)

Comment: @LPs  After the interviewer (you) questioned my code , I quickly re-worked to the corrected understanding.

Comment: The job is yours! +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking to see if either the first digit in `arr` is 5 or more to check if the `newarr` array needs to be 1 larger than the original array.

So something like this for initialization:

```
int* newarr;
int  newlen;
if (*arr >= 5)
     newlen = len + 1; 
else
     newlen = len;

newarr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * newlen);   
memset(newarr, 0, newlen); //initialize all newarr values to 0
```

Now obviously we have to do our multiplication now. To get the 1's digit we do use the modulo operator `%`, and to get the 10's digit we use the division operator `/`. Of course we only need to do the division if our multiplied value is 10 or greater. So our loop to populate `newarr` will look something like this:

```
int i, temp;
for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    temp = *(arr + i - 1) * 2;
    if (temp < 10) {
        *(newarr + i - 1) += temp;
    }
    else {
        *(newarr + i - 1) += temp / 10; //inset 10's digit
        *(newarr + i) += temp % 10; //inset 1's digit 
    }

}
```

So our full function ends up being

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int* multTwo(int* arr, int len)
{

    int* newarr;
    int  newlen;
    if (*arr >= 5)
        newlen = len + 1; 
    else
        newlen = len;

    newarr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * newlen);   
    memset(newarr, 0, newlen); //initialize all newarr values to 0

    int i, temp;
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        temp = *(arr + i - 1) * 2;
        if (temp < 10) {
            *(newarr + i - 1) += temp;
        }
        else {
            *(newarr + i - 1) += temp / 10; //insert 10's digit
            *(newarr + i) += temp % 10; //inset 1's digit 
        }

    }
    return newarr; //don't forget to free once you're done with newarr!        
}
```

Comment: _I would start by looking to see **if either the last or first digit** in arr is 5 or more to check if the newarr array needs to be 1 larger than the original array._ I agree for the first but not for the last digit

Comment: @LPs Thanks, your comment made me realize I had a slight misunderstanding of OP's question. Fixed now.